# Is there a way to SELECT * and do a CASE expression

Tags: sql, teradata

So something like this:

```
SELECT *, 
CASE 
    WHEN
....
```

I'm coding in Teradata

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier for you to just try doing this?  I mean, either it works or it doesn't.  If it _doesn't_ work, then you'll need to list out all columns explicitly.

Comment: ......I did try.......I thought that maybe there mgiht be a format that would work that I didn't know of................

Answer (score 1):

In Teradata if you are going to include more derived columns with your `*` then you must include the table or alias name with the `*`

So:

```
  SELECT 
      myTable.*, 
      myOtherTable.*,
      CASE WHEN... END 
  FROM myTable
      INNER JOIN myOtherTable ON
          mytable.id = myOtherTable.id;
```

If you have a thousand tables being joined together then just toss that mess into a subquery so you can `SELECT * FROM` and then add you case in the main query:

```
 SELECT t1.*
     CASE WHEN... END
 FROM
     (
         SELECT *
         FROM myTable
              INNER JOIN myOtherTable ON
                  mytable.id = myOtherTable.id
     ) AS t1;
```

Comment: Thanks very much <3